# Custom BottomSheet Behavior | More States | AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I want to be able to add more states to my current BottomSheet with multiple **custom** heights.

Right now, the AndroidX bottom sheet only has the following states: STATE_HIDDEN, STATE_HALF_EXPANDED, STATE_EXPANDED, STATE_COLLAPSED, STATE_DRAGGING, STATE_SETTLING.

Is there any way to add states/heights to the "BottomSheetBehavior" class?

Solutions I've considered:

- There is a lot of material on this for the **support** version of the BottomSheet (and most of them stem from copy/pasting the code and modifying behavior) however almost none for the **com.google.android.material.bottomsheet**
- I've considered extending the BottomSheetBehavior class and manually altering it's behavior however this will take a lot of work/analysis to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achive that you want.

First same solution like yours. There are a lot of examples of adding new states - like [this](https://github.com/trafi/anchor-bottom-sheet-behavior/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/trafi/anchorbottomsheetbehavior/AnchorBottomSheetBehavior.java). As you can see, they just copy class of BottomSheetBehavior and make some modification.

**Why it was done like that?** Because most important fields that you need to modify are **internal** or **private**. There is no way to make modification by inheritance in case with **private** fields. You can check [this](https://github.com/trafi/anchor-bottom-sheet-behavior/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/trafi/anchorbottomsheetbehavior/AnchorBottomSheetBehavior.java) anchor behavior and watch the difference with original in material repo. If all fields that you need to modify is **internal** you can make a child of bottom sheet behavior and place it in same package as bottom sheet behavior - check example [here](https://github.com/HeyAlex/CornerSheet/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/CornerMaterialSheetBehavior.kt) (this behavior is mine and i prefer this solutions, since all fields that i need is **internal**. check package of this class - it has same package name as BottomSheetBehavior). In this case you can modify fields. Both solutions are ugly. There is nothing we can do with this strange api of *BottomSheetBehavior*

Comment: Yep, thanks for the answer. I went with manually altering my BottomSheetBehavior. It works fine for the most part...although the anchorage and movement is a bit weird (I don't know if that's normal but I left it as is).

Comment: @HeyAlex maybe you know, how to apply custom bottom sheet behavior to ModalBottomSheet?

Comment: @JackTheHealer sorry for missing your comment for a long time! i suggest you to write it by yourself. where is no way to change it without any hacky variants, which can fit production code imo

Comment: @HeyAlex i found the way. later i write solution in my own question :)